# Bluetooth USB Dongle not Working on Ubuntu Focal

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth

I recently bought a Bluetooth dongle but Ubuntu doesn't seem to activate it. I tried following some of the threads in this forum but it didn't work. Here's the output of a few useful commmands:

```
~$ blueman-manager

(blueman-manager:11660): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:19:20.240: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:6342:10: 'height' is not a valid property name
blueman-manager version 2.1.2 starting
blueman-manager 23.19.20 ERROR    Manager:118 on_dbus_name_appeared: Default adapter not found, trying first available.
blueman-manager 23.19.20 ERROR    Manager:122 on_dbus_name_appeared: No adapter(s) found, exiting
```

```
~$ rfkill list
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

```
~$ bluetoothctl 
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# scan on
No default controller available
[bluetooth]# power on
No default controller available
[bluetooth]#
```

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2021-03-16 19:23:58 -03; 3h 59min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 6926 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 9415)
     Memory: 1.1M
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─6926 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

mar 16 19:23:58 user systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
mar 16 19:23:58 user bluetoothd[6926]: Bluetooth daemon 5.53
mar 16 19:23:58 user bluetoothd[6926]: Starting SDP server
mar 16 19:23:58 user systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
mar 16 19:23:58 user bluetoothd[6926]: Bluetooth management interface 1.17 initialized
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It reads like your hardware is not present. Does this adapter work with Ubuntu? Have you tested it in any other computer or OS?

Comment: Hi @David. Yes, I tried it on Windows and it works fine. Do you think it isn't compatible with Linux at all?

Comment: I just talked to the seller and they told me it doesn't work on Linux